# cmp and ja question

Tags: assembly, gdb, disassembly, instructions

I'm having problems understanding this. It's in intel syntax

```
cmp eax, 0x19
ja greater
```

eax contains the value -40. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow tells me ja is the unsigned comparison from the previous cmp.

As far as I know, this should jump IF arg1 (0x19) is ABOVE arg2 (0xffffffd8)

0x19 looks smaller than 0xffffffd8 to me. The jump is being performed. Any help understanding my flawed logic much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a little hard to answer because different assemblers reverse the order of operands. From the looks of things, you seem to be using Intel syntax assembly, in which case what you have is roughly equivalent to `if (unsigned)eax > 0x19 goto greater`. That being the case, it's reasonable that the jump is taken.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The information on the webpage was confusing. It showed intel syntax as cmp arg2, arg1 and then later on said ja jump if "first operation" is above the second. It didn't specify syntax

Comment: @kisplit: Perhaps it's easier if you consider that `cmp a,b` is equivalent to `sub a, b`, except that it only changes the flags, where `sub` changes the flags *and* puts the difference in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, 0xffffffd8 is a negative number in two's complement 32 bit.  0x19 is positive.